# What's the difference between using the/a/(nothing) in this sentence?

Tags: articles

What's the difference between using the/a/(nothing) in this sentence? What's the difference between definite and indefinite article? What about not using them at all - would it be still correct?
"Breaking the/a/(no article) boundaries of fear."

Answer (score 1):

- *Breaking **a** boundaries* doesn't work because a/an can only be used with singular nouns. *Boundaries* is plural.
- Both *breaking **the** boundaries* and *breaking boundaries* are fine, the former implying *all the* boundaries, and the latter implying *some of the* boundaries.

Comment: Or one could use singular *boundary* and say either "breaking a boundary" or "breaking the boundary", depending on the metaphor intended.